# Continuity of $F(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fd\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

For a homework assignment I was told to prove that given $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$, the following function is continuous $$F(x)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}fd\lambda.$$

I thought to use DCT and show sequential continuity. So given $x_n\rightarrow x$, we look at the sequence of indicators $\mathbf 1_{(-\infty,x_n]}f$. These are dominated by $|f|$ which is in $L^1$ iff $f$ is, which we know. So by DCT $$\lim _n \int \mathbf 1_{(-\infty,x_n]}f=\int \mathbf 1_{(-\infty,x]}f$$ as desired. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine.

Comment: To apply DCT, you have to prove that $1_{(-\infty, x_n]}(t) f(t) \to 1_{(-\infty, x]}(t) f(t)$ for almost every $t$.  It would be wise to check this carefully.  In particular, note that depending on the sequence $x_n$ and the function $f$, you may not get convergence at $t=x$.  (But that's okay because $\{x\}$ is a set of measure zero.)

Comment: It seems to me this follows almost immediately from the definition of integrable.  $F(x)-F(y)$ is the integral over a small interval if $y$ is close to $x$ and has to go to zero in the limit.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $F$ is *uniformly* continuous in $\mathbb R$.

To see this, let $\varepsilon>0$ and set $g_n(x)=\min\{\lvert\, f(x)\rvert,n\}$. By virtue of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that
$\|g_n-\lvert\, f\rvert\|_{L^1}\to 0$.

Fix $N>0$, such that $\|g_N-\lvert\, f\rvert\|_{L^1}<\varepsilon/2$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}g_N\,dx\le \int_{\mathbb R}\lvert\, f\rvert\,dx\le\int_{\mathbb R}g_N\,dx+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$

Set $\,\delta=\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{2N+1}\,$ and let $\,\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta.\,$ Then
$$
\lvert\,F(x)-F(y)\rvert=\left|\int_x^y f(t)\,dt\,\right|\le\int_x^y \lvert\,f(t)\rvert\,dt\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\int_x^y g_N(t)\,dt
\\ \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+N\lvert x-y\rvert
\le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+N\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{2N+1}<\varepsilon.
$$